# Solrj alternative to setDefaultCollection

Tags: solr, solrj

I only see one way of specifying the collection while adding indices to Solr through Solrj.  Can I do it per-request?

```
SolrServer server = new SolrServer("someurl")
server.setDefaultCollection( "events" );

server.addBean( item );
```

Digging into the Solrj code, I see that it honors the "collection" parameter on the SolrRequest, but I haven't found a way to set it:

```
String collection = reqParams.get("collection", defaultCollection);
```

Is there another way besides @Overriding the request method?

Comment: Where would you want to pass the "requst-based default-core"? Within the SolrQuery object?

Comment: If possible, doesn't seem like its exposed, however